# How to disable EF Migration code first Default Value generation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-6.0

I am using EF Core 6 Code First approach. When I define a new entity with a **required** field, EF migrations create for that *always* an empty default constraint like here:

```cs
           migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<Guid>(
                name: "TenantId",
                table: "Sites",
                type: "uniqueidentifier",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"),  // unnecessary default constraint
                oldClrType: typeof(Guid),
                oldType: "uniqueidentifier",
                oldNullable: true);
```

In most cases, I do not want to have **any** default value. I tried to disable this behavior with a model configuration like this, but it has no effect:

```cs
  builder.Property(cc => cc.TenantId).HasDefaultValue(null);
  builder.Property(cc => cc.TenantId).HasDefaultValueSql(null);
```

I am using this command for generating the migrations:

```
 dotnet ef migrations add --context:DataContext --project "xxx" xxxx
```

I couldn't find any question on SO for this particular issue, but there are a lot of similar questions leading to one answer: *just update the generated scripts manually*.

That feels strange to me. So far, I have never updated the scripts manually, I think a manual update to the script will lead to a discrepancy between the code and the DB schema. If the manual change in the script is the way to go, could you please explain why that is not a problem and why I should not be worried?

many thanks!

---

additional details:

```
// Nullable types are not enabled

public class Site
{
    public Tenant Tenant { get; set; }

    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class Tenant
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class SiteEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Site>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Site> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(cc => cc.Tenant)
            .WithMany()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your POCO model code of TenantId property? Is it a nullable Guid? Are there any Attributes? Updating the generated scripts manually is definitely the wrong approach, since your model snapshot will still be a false representation of your schema. Keep that in mind.

Comment: sure, sorry, I included the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea, I think, is to allow database migrations. That is, to be able to update a live database incrementally. This means that new columns MUST have a default value, or else you would not be able to apply a migration that adds a column if there was any data in the table. (The new column needs a source of values for the existing rows.)

Notice that if the table is being newly created rather than adding a new column to an existing table, then the column does not get a default value specifier unless you add one.

For the most part, column default values in the DB shouldn't matter too much when using EF since I think EF will always give a value for each column explicitly.

Comment: You are right, indeed, new tables do not suffer from this behavior, it happens only when a column is altered or added.

Still, it would be great if I could control the behavior, in case you are altering columns where you know that all values are filled and you mark them as required, you might want to omit the default constraint.

Comment: I will accept your answer, as my question does not specify whether I create a new table or change an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Well....you shouldn't worry, but then maybe you should.

You ***shouldn't*** worry about manually changing the script because it doesn't really affect the runtime behavior.  The default value only affects the SQL side of things and not the POCO side.

In other words, if you create a new instance of the POCO, whatever default constraints you have (or do not have) in the database have no effect on the values in that new POCO instance.

However, you **should** worry about it from a code maintenance perspective, which is why I came to this thread also looking for a way to prevent the default constraint from being created in the first place.  If we had a way to do this we could make our code self-documenting for other developers and ourselves in the future when we look at it and ask, "why does this column not have a default constraint yet all the others do?".

Comment: Thanks, you described it very well. That is exactly my concern; the discrepancy between POCO and SQL after the manual change will become confusing, eventually. Merging migrations into a single file (after a while, when there are too many migrations) will become complicated too.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot have a [Required] property have a null default value. This would be against the constraint.

If a property is required, it will be marked as NON NULLable in the database. So you cannot use null as default.

Comment: my goal is to have a 'none' constraint, not a null-default. I am trying to convince the EF script generator to omit the Default value completely.

Comment: What is a "none" constraint? How do you wish your SQL column- and constraint- definitions to look like?

Comment: Meaning, there is no default constraint created on that table for that column. If there is no default constraint created, a value has to be provided by the user in order to insert a row into the Database.

Comment: Just remove the defaultValue / HasDefaultValue entirely.

Comment: I would like to do that, but that is my point - if I remove defaultValue from the migration scripts, I will have a discrepancy between the POCO models and generated Migrations. Why is that not a problem?